# Is Cūḷa Suññata Sutta a prelude to Bahiya Sutta?

Tags: sunyata

The [Cūḷa Suññata Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.121.than.html) gives a progressive means of experiencing sunyata.  The [Bahiya Sutta (UD)](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.10.irel.html) tells of an interaction between Buddha and the Brahmin Bahiya - Buddha advises Bahiya to get right on the surface of things without any dwelling (bhava):

*“And since for you, Bāhiya, in what is seen there will be only what is seen, in what is heard there will be only what is heard, in what is sensed there will be only what is sensed, in what is cognized there will be only what is cognized, therefore, Bāhiya, you will not be with that; and since, Bāhiya, you will not be with that, therefore, Bāhiya, you will not be in that; and since, Bāhiya, you will not be in that, therefore, Bāhiya, you will not be here or hereafter or in between the two—just this is the end of suffering.”*

Is the admonishment given to Bahiya a corollary to the **themeless concentration (signless immersion of the heart)** described in Cūḷa Suññata Sutta?  If Bahiya has not realized sunyata can he adhere to Buddha's words?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to talk about the advanced phases of Buddha's original path in the Canon, because no one can say with certainty that he or she understands exactly what those brief and cryptic Canon descriptions mean. Many people claim they "kind of" understand and have reproduced these phases, but their explanations don't match, and we don't have the Buddha available to confirm who of them got it right.

Luckily we know enough about Buddhism's underlying *principles* to recover *the overall system*, and this can help us figure out the meaning of these obscure passages.

First of all, there's no doubt for me that Buddhist liberation (whether we call it the end of suffering, or just Liberation in a broader sense) is about transcending the limits of mental constructs. It's clear to me that dukkha arises as a clash or irresolvable contradiction within a stream of experience. The clash, in its turn arises from mental constructs contradicting each other or contradicting reality. In a way, all mental constructs are simplifications, so as long as you attach to them as something complete and valid, you are prone to suffering.

This gives us enough context to understand Buddha's Noble Truths and his "liberation through wisdom" *in principle*. Once you clearly understand how exactly suffering arises and see the issue with attachment to mental constructs, you can learn to stop grasping, getting immune to suffering and free from all limits.

Another thing we can clearly see from the suttas is that most of the time Buddha taught a gradual, incremental method of implementation of these principles. First, one has to remove the coarse suffering by removing the coarse causes of coarse suffering. Then go to the harder to see and more subtle but also more fundamental types of suffering. There are many steps on this ladder.

All of the above is pretty clear but it is rather high-level understanding in broad strokes. What gets more difficult is to understand the step by step instructions given in the Canon. There are several different progressions given in the suttas, describing alternative ways to proceed.

One major variation of the path goes through the Four Jhanas. As I explained many times on this site, the Four Jhanas do not talk about the *content* of mind as a kind of fixed state, but rather about one's *attitude* to experience on each of the four stages. The meditator learns to overcome mind's tendency to create suffering by setting expectations and comparing them with reality. The process goes through several stages of refinement, until the meditator scrutinizes one's attitude to this meditation itself - one's motives and expectations - culminating in the direct non-intellectual experience of Tathata. This is known as the desireless door to Nirvana.

Another variant we see in the suttas is the one that goes through the Formless Ayatanas (never called "jhanas" in the Canon!) and the signless absorption. This one is also an incremental progression from coarse to subtle, but instead of reflecting on one's *attitude and expectations*, the meditator engages in the direct non-intellectual study of mental constructs and the workings of subject-object mind. The idea is to get a first-hand look at how all constructs are relative and how subject and object are two sides of the same coin. To do this, one scrutinizes one's mental experience of objects delineated against a series of ever-expanding backgrounds. First, spatial objects against the background of "space", then, the mental experience of "space" against the background of one's "consciousness", then reflect at one's own "consciousness" taken as an experience against the background of "nothing". (The key insight to gain from this practice is how each of these consecutive backgrounds serves as the subject observing the previous object, this subject itself becoming an object of an even deeper subject on the next step and so on.)

Then there is a stage that I don't fully understand - the Neither-Perception-Nor-Non-Perception. I don't think anyone *really* knows what that means. We know it must be more refined than the previous one, so it's probably some kind of background against which the experience of "nothing" is delineated and recognized by the mind.

What I do understand is the next stage: at that point meditator realizes that even recognizing "nothing" is an act of semiosis and finally arrives at the mind that does not perform any semiosis whatsoever -- not grasping at and not interpreting any signs. This is the signless absorption.

And then, as Buddha always says, one realizes that even though the signless absorption is absolutely free from suffering, sitting in this sterile bubble is not something that can last for infinity, because it is a conditioned situation that sooner or later ends. So the value of the signless absorption is not in it being one's final destination, but in giving the meditator direct non-intellectual understanding of how our experience of world and the self is just a bunch of mental constructs and therefore should not be taken too seriously. This is known as the signless door to Nirvana.

If you take a 40-thousand-feet-high look at both of the doors, you can see that the common theme there, in both cases the meditator does not stay within a sterile state of no expectations/desires as in the Fourth Jhana or the still mind of the signless absorption. Instead, both of these doors lead to the same breakthrough to the unconditioned non-abiding Tathata, the perfect attainment of the Third Noble Truth right in the middle of samsara.

Now, when we look at the Bahiya Sutta, we can assume that the Buddha is most likely talking about the very end of the path. Bahiya is presented as an advanced student who had enough reasons to think he could have been an arahant. Unlike in the  Cūḷa Suññata Sutta, with Bahiya the Buddha skips all the gradual teaching and gets right to the heart of the matter. Finally, at the end of the sutta Buddha declares that Bahiya has attained the final Nirvana. Clearly, he was a very advanced student ready to receive the most advanced teaching.

To me, the way Buddha talks about the seen, the heard, the cognized etc. *being just what it is*, looks like he talks about Tathata - the experience of an arahant.

Could he be talking about the signless absorption? I don't think so, first and foremost because in silent absorption one does not delineate the Ayatanas of the seen, the heard, or the cognized. The signless absorption is even beyond the Ayatana of Infinite Nothing and the one that goes after it. But here we are talking about Seen, Heard, Cognized as separate modalities. Clearly this is not the signless absorption.

Another useful detail Buddha adds is "you will not be 'with that' ... you will not be 'in that'". This reminds me of Buddha's teaching about *anatta* and how we should abandon habitual thinking "I am that; I am with that; I am in that" and so on - regarding any and all phenomena.

Finally, the Buddha concludes by equating this attainment with the end of suffering, the very Goal of Dharma. Is the signless absorption the Goal? No, the Buddha himself said it is not.

Instead, Buddha says, seeing what is seen, cognizing what is cognized without grasping at mental constructs, "you will be neither here nor beyond nor in between the two". In other words, neither in samsara ("here"), nor in the sterile bubble of samadhi ("beyond"), but in the groundless non-abiding nirvana.

So I think what Buddha describes there is quite simply the perspective of an arahant, not any intermediate stage preceding arahantship. Arahant looks at things with a dispassionate mind, [not grasping at signs](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/48916/43), seeing things yata-bhuta (as they are) without adding his or her expectations, attitude, or indeed anything related to self.

Based on all of the above, I think the answer to your question is: yes, the teaching in Bahiya Sutta logically goes after the teaching in Cūḷa Suññata Sutta.

Remember how I said the Four Jhanas is the desireless door to Nirvana and the Shunyata is the signless door? These are two alternative paths and the Bahiya Sutta describes where you get after walking either of them to the end.

So, yes, Bahiya must have either realized shunyata or have attained all four jhanas before meeting the Buddha, otherwise he would not be able to understand and perfectly implement the final instructions. Too bad he was stupid enough to get killed by a cow, otherwise he could have grown to be the second Shariputra, starting his own school of Buddhism, who knows ;)

Comment: >Too bad he was stupid enough to get killed by a cow. Not all cows are docile. And any large male wild animal in heat (mating season) can become aggresive and very dangerous.

Comment: Did you find that hilarious? Me too. A zen style joke right in the middle of the Pali Canon.

Comment: Are ayantanas the organs or indriya?

Comment: No, Ayatanas are like subjective spaces or dimensions where experiences exist. Visible experiences are inside the Ayatana of "the realm of the visible", mental experiences are inside the Ayatana "the consciousness" or "the realm of the mental experiences" and so on. Space and Nothingness are also Ayatanas. With space it is easy to understand because all external objects are experienced inside "the realm of space". What they called Nothingness is also an Ayatana but that Ayatana requires deep concentration to see.

Comment: Indriya is eye-consciousness, etc  right?

Comment: Indriya is any power or faculty, like the power to see, the power to hear, the power of wisdom, any type of natural or supernatural power one has. The ancients didn't think in the same exact terms that we have, like "organs".

Comment: >A zen style joke right in the middle of the Pali Canon - Can you explain? I'm not too familiar with non pali based texts.

Comment: I'm sorry, explaining Zen is bad style.

Answer (score 2):

The Bahiya Sutta is not about the Signless. The content of the Bahiya Sutta is explained in detail in [SN 35.95](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.95/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true).

Answer (score 0):

Bahiya sutta which tells Dhamma in brief is not a corollary to Emptiness sutta. It is the summary of Emptiness sutta. Although Dhamma can be described in brief , it is difficult to follow it if not accompanied by action. Imagine saying, seen is just seen and it is not you ,yours or yourself. It is easier said than done. You need a venerable Teacher to induce that belief in us. Whereas Sunyata sutta shows you how you can achieve by letting go of perceptions of cities , villages , people , earth , space , consciousness, neither perception nor non-perception , signless immersion of heart , defilements of sensuality, desire to be reborn etc. It is a step by step process to achieve Nibbana by meditating on Emptiness by letting go. You can meditate on Impermanence to get the same effect of dispassion and cessation or you can meditate on Ugliness to achieve same effect or you can meditate on Dhamma in brief to achieve nirvana or meditate on five aggregates to achieve nirvana… All are equivalent with varying degrees of difficulty.